# cause for python 3.4.3 IDLE and windows shell input() inconsistencies?

Tags: python-3.x, input, cmd

I am running a python program from the windows command prompt (windows 8.1, python 3.4.3 64-bit). In troubleshooting why input() was not working for me the same in IDLE as in cmd.exe I discovered that while IDLE is handling the result from input() correctly (i.e. as a str type), the cmd.exe processes the input incorrectly. Specifically, cmd.exe stores a value according to the type given: a number is stored as an int type, or as a float type if a float is given, a string without quotations raises a NameError, and with quotations a value is stored as a str stype. Is there a valid reason why cmd.exe would be incorrectly handling input(). The tester program I used to see this for myself is below.

```
def input_tester():
    x = input("Input: ")    
    print(x, type(x))
while True:
    input_tester()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add this as a comment but it won't let me because of my rep. I would suggest trying `eval(input())` in place of your `input()`. See if that helps.

Comment: Hi. You're suggestion helped, as using eval(input()) in the script invoked the same behavior in IDLE as I was getting from input() in cmd.exe. This made me realise that although I was using python 3 IDLE, and if I ran python in cmd.exe it loaded the python 3 environment, loading .py scripts directly in cmd.exe was loading them in a python 2 environment instead. I have resolved this by uninstalling python 2 and reinstalling 3. Thank you!